# How to schedule a chain task in celery

Tags: celery, schedule, chain

I want to run a complex task scheduled by beat. Let us assume the default add/mul tasks are defined.

```py
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(),
        add.s(2,3) | mul.s(2)
    )
```

But this will return an error in the worker:

```
NotImplementedError: chain is not a real task
```

How can I schedule a non trivial task with celery beat?

Comment: I suggest you use beat configuration and schedule your task to run however/whenever you like there... Also, use beat as a separate service...

Comment: I have used a beat schedule (as given above). But the task has to depend on the previous result and is therefore a chain task. However celery beat FAILS when i provide it a chain task with the error given above.

Comment: I would wrap that chain in a task, and add it to the beatconfig...

Comment: as recommended by @DejanLekic wrapping the chain (or a group or chains in my case) in a task worked for me. The only extra thing I had to do was to actually call the group  with `.delay()` inside the task definition.
Without that, the main task was scheduled fine but the linked tasks where never triggered.

Tested with  Celery  5.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do that is to schedule your tasks chain in `beat_schedule` in your `celeryconfig`, using `link` option, `celery_tasks` here is a module name where your tasks are defined

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery import signature

beat_schedule = {
    'chained': {
        'task': 'celery_tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(),
        'options': {
            'queue': 'default',
            'link': signature('celery_tasks.mul',
                        args=(),
                        kwargs={},
                        options={
                            'link': signature('celery_tasks.another_task', 
                                args=(),
                                kwargs={}, 
                                queue='default')
                        },
                        queue='default')
            },
         'args': ()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this now. The chained task is accepted, but not executed by the worker., The beat service states
```[2019-06-06 13:22:00,034: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task chained (tasks.add)```
but the worker does not react at all.

Additionally, can I link more then one task? I eventually will need 4 linked tasks (object loader, dmap (distribute to group), load_data, process_data).

Comment: Is your worker listen to the queue you've specified in `beat_schedule`?

Comment: I am only editing a single file `tasks.py`.
I have done more experiments. I have added the task schedule as above (see code). Only the `tasks.add` task is executed.
//edit: I forgot there was the second "queue" argument in the link-dict. For the add|mul task it seems to work now. I will have to test with my more complex schedule next. Thanks.

Comment: To run more linked tasks you can add `link` attribute to `options` in your previous linked task. I've updated my answer to demonstrate this

Comment: You are welcome! Note, that I ended up using just `Cron` to run periodic tasks in production as I couldn't force celery-beat to work properly, may be it was fixed in the latest versions of Celery though

Comment: According to the latest documentation (5.1.2): 
`In practice the link execution option is considered an internal primitive, and you’ll probably not use it directly, but use chains instead.`
[Linking (callbacks/errbacks)](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks)

Comment: Good catch! The original solution was devised for celery 4.x, so there could be a better one for the newest version

Answer (score 0):

for add chained periodic tasks you can use an @app.task when declare your chain and then, add this new task on add_periodic_task() method. Example:

```
@app.on_after_finalize.connect ->i use this because it`s declared on task.py
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):                               
   sender.add_periodic_task(timedelta(minutes=10), chian_st22.s(),name='test')
                                

@app.task
def chian_st22(): -> i create the task with chain 
    cadena = chain(st22.s(), mailer.s()).apply_async()

@app.task
def mailer(data):
    clase = CheckAlert()
    mail = clase.envio_mail(data)
    return mail

@app.task
def st22():
    clase = CheckAlert()
    st = clase.check_st22_dumps()
    return st
```